# Create a partition with fdisk in bytes

Tags: partition, fdisk

i would like to create a partition with fdisk with exact number of bytes. 
But fdisk only let me input K,M,G,T,P:

```
   Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-7814037134, default 7814037134)
```

Comment: _"If the size is prefixed by  '+' then it is interpreted as relative to the partition first sector. **In this case the  size  is  expected  in  bytes**  and  the number  may be followed by the multiplicative suffixes..."_

Answer (score 2):

You were asked the "last sector" or the "size" of the partition which you want to create. This can be something such as (for example): +1GB or +3100M. If you press enter without entering a value, then the whole space available on the disk is created by fdisk.

Answer (score 1):

You can only create partitions with a size that is a number of sectors of the disc, and as your output shows fdisk ask for a sector number (or allows you to use a unit that is a multiple of the sector size.